# Why partially initializing a class and then invoking delegating ctor fails?

Tags: c++, delegating-constructor

Following code does not initialize struct string members to same value.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    S(std::string const& s) : s1{s}{}
    S(int i) : S([&]{
        s2 = std::to_string(i);
        return std::to_string(i);
    }())
    {}
};

int main()
{
    S s{123};
    std::cout << s.s1 << "|" << s.s2;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting segmentation fault in gcc (tried different versions),
and `123|` in clang (different versions also) through Wandbox.

I'm getting a read access violation Visual Studio 15.9.16

Thank you.

Comment: @Moia there is call () at end of expression.

Comment: Which is the expected value of `S("toto").s2`?

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie defining a constructor and calling a constructor are two different things. To call a constructor you have to define a constructor with thode arguments

Comment: @Moia the lamdba is immediately invoked to yield a `std::string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument you give to the constructor (i.e. the lambda) cannot access internal members, because they have not been constructed yet.

This should work:

```
struct S
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    S(std::string const& s) : s1{s}{}
    S(int i)
      : S(std::to_string(i))
    {
        s2 = s1;
    }
};
```

Comment: More generally this means that when evaluating argument for any ctor, the class member "does non exist yet"?

Comment: @user1832484 you are trying to use it as parameter to the constructor, ie even before the constructor is called

Comment: @user1832484 no, they simply weren't constructed before you call another constructor of this class, so yes, whole object wasn't created yet.You cannot change order of creation, even if you write that section in wrong order. `s2` always initialized after `s1`, both done after constructor call but before enetering its body.

Comment: @user1832484: The class members are constructed before the opening brace of the constructor. In this case your constructor _delegates_ to another constructor to construct the members, so they do not exist until after that has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting an uninitialized object is an UB, in this case it'd been obscured by this string:

```
       s2 = std::to_string(i);
```

It's a  call to `operator=` of `std::string` for object stored at location of `s2`.
It wasn't initialized at that point yet. I assume that you could fix it by initializing `s2`, but it's not possible to do before constructor call in initialization list.

You cannot change order of creation, even if you write that section in wrong order. `s2` always initialized after `s1`, both done after constructor call but before entering its body. Thus the order looks like:

1. Call of ctor `S(int)` with initialization of argument `i`;
2. Creation of lambda object, capturing `this` and `i`
3. Call of operator() of lambda
4. **Call `operator=` of `std::string` for object stored at location of `s2`**
5. Creation of `std::string`
6. Delegating call of ctor `S(std::string)` with argument `s`  with reference to created string.
7. Initialization of `s1` with value of `s`
8. **Default initialization of `s2`**

Bullets 4. and 8. happen in order which isn't legal, even worse, due to implementation, it may not to yield an error, so gcc version likely writes that data into some random area of memory. MSVC, at least in debug version, may generate some diagnostic code, for standard doesn't define program behavior for such case.